# SASS Style is not fully loaded

Tags: angular, typescript, sass

I'm doing an Angular 11 project, and actually on some pages, while I load the page, the style is not fully loaded.

I mean, for exemple, that the style for the card tags is loaded, but the text's style inside isn't loaded until I refresh (F5) or delete the cache (Ctrl + Maj + R).

The .scss file is called in the component constructor :

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './informations.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./informations.component.scss'],
})
```

The problem appears randomly, but always on the same elements.

Did somebody know how to resolve that ?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: you probably have browser cache on, turn off cache

Comment: @MikeTung unfortunately, that did not resolve the problem